# Reformatting a query result in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, sqlalchemy

SQL queries allow not just to get a bunch of columns as a result but form it into something usefult at the same time. E.g.:

```
select Person.name + " likes " + Food.name as all_i_want_as_a_result from Food, Person where Food.id == Person.favourite_food
```

But how can I do the same with SQLAlchemy? E.g.:

```
query = db.session.query(Food, Person).filter(Food.id == Person.favourite_food) <-- how do I modify this line?
for row in db.session.execute(query)
    print row
```

The expected output would be:

```
Alice likes icecream
Bob likes pizza
```

Comment: Hi, We both edited at the same time and broke the system. Can you please re-[edit] the post. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No worries. But it looks ok to me, nothing I would change.

Comment: Thanks for changing *beef* to *burger*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for arbitrary things inside `.query()`:

```
query = db.session.query(Person.name.concat(" likes ").concat(Food.name).label("all_i_want_as_a_result"))
                  .filter(Food.id == Person.favourite_food)
print query
```

This prints:

```
SELECT "Person".name || ? || "Food".name AS all_i_want_as_a_result 
FROM "Person", "Food" 
WHERE "Food".id = "Person".favourite_food
```